# Ruby/GTK+ app done correctly?

Tags: ruby, gtk

I'm building a UI for a Ruby application using the GTK+3 gem and Glade/Builder. I've cobbled some stuff together from samples in the [Github repository's samples](https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/tree/master/gtk3/sample/gtk-demo) and it mostly works fine. At its simplest my code is:

```
require 'gtk3'
class Main < Gtk::Window
   def initialize
     super(:toplevel)
     set_title('My App')
     @builder = Gtk::Builder.new
     @builder << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'my-app.glade')
     @builder.connect_signals { |name| method(name)}
     @window = @builder["app-main"]
     @window.show
   end

   private
   def quit_application
     @window.destroy
     destroy unless destroyed?
     Gtk.main_quit
   end
end

Gtk.init
window = Main.new
Gtk.main
```

Does this make sense? The code seems to load create a subclass of Gtk::Window but then loads the actual window being displayed in to a variable.

In the above link, under `tutorial`, there are samples that subclass `Gtk::Application` and `Gtk::ApplicationWindow` classes that look nicer to me, but I couldn't get any of them to run.

Comment: You're not using a composite widget template in that code snippet. You're just creating another window as an instance variable of your GtkWindow subclass and showing that. Unfortunately, I don't know how the composite widget template machinery works in Ruby, but I can tell you in C we use the `gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child_private()` and `gtk_widget_init_template()` functions to make it work. Make sure your .ui file is marked as a composite widget template as well :) In Glade, there's a checkbox "Composite" next to the toplevel widget name that you need to check.

Comment: Sorry - I was meaning to ask a question about composited widgets, but then decided that I may not have the basics done correctly, but I forgot to change the title. Its fixed now.